# fatal error: GL/glx.h: No such file or directory libgl1-mesa-dev already installed

Tags: c++, skia, glx

I'm trying to compile skia to compile aseprite on Ubuntu 19.10, I keep getting the error

```
c++ -MMD -MF obj/src/gpu/gl/glx/gpu.GrGLMakeNativeInterface_glx.o.d -DNDEBUG -DSK_SAMPLES_FOR_X -DSK_GAMMA_APPLY_TO_A8 -DSK_ALLOW_STATIC_GLOBAL_INITIALIZERS=0 -DSK_ENABLE_DISCRETE_GPU -DSKIA_IMPLEMENTATION=1 -I../../include/android -I../../include/c -I../../include/codec -I../../include/config -I../../include/core -I../../include/docs -I../../include/effects -I../../include/encode -I../../include/gpu -I../../include/atlastext -I../../include/pathops -I../../include/ports -I../../include/svg -I../../include/utils -I../../include/utils/mac -I../../include/private -I../../src/c -I../../src/codec -I../../src/core -I../../src/effects -I../../src/fonts -I../../src/image -I../../src/images -I../../src/lazy -I../../src/opts -I../../src/pathops -I../../src/pdf -I../../src/ports -I../../src/sfnt -I../../src/shaders -I../../src/shaders/gradients -I../../src/sksl -I../../src/utils -I../../src/utils/win -I../../src/xml -I../../third_party/gif -I../../src/gpu -fstrict-aliasing -fPIC -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++14 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -c ../../src/gpu/gl/glx/GrGLMakeNativeInterface_glx.cpp -o obj/src/gpu/gl/glx/gpu.GrGLMakeNativeInterface_glx.o
../../src/gpu/gl/glx/GrGLMakeNativeInterface_glx.cpp:15:10: fatal error: GL/glx.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <GL/glx.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

all the posts I've found have said to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` using apt-get, but I've already done that and I'm still getting the error. I've also tried running `install_dependencies.sh` in the `tools` folder, which installed a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the glx file file and copy it to your project file this will fix the error but us not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had set apt-get to use the oibaf ppa for graphics drivers, purging the ppa and reinstalling from the standard sources fixed it.